# What is the best way to find the user's home directory in Java?

Tags: java, cross-platform, home-directory

What is the best way to find the user's home directory in Java?

The difficulty is that the solution should be cross-platform; it should work on Windows 2000, XP, Vista, OS X, Linux, and other Unix variants. I am looking for a snippet of code that can accomplish this for all platforms, and a way to detect the platform.

Per Java bug [4787931](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4787931), system property `user.home` does not work correctly on Windows XP, so using this system property is not an acceptable solution as it is not cross-platform.

Comment: Did you try the workarounds mentioned in the bug? There are plenty of suggestions.

Comment: bug 4787931 for java versions up through 1.4.2 shows up again as bug 6519127 for java 1.6.  The problem is not going away and is still listed as low priority.

Comment: Note: bug 4787391 is marked as fixed in Java 8

Comment: For a discussion on Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1503555/873282.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

The bug you reference (bug 4787391) has been fixed in Java 8. Even if you are using an older version of Java, the `System.getProperty("user.home")` approach is probably still the best. The `user.home` approach seems to work in a very large number of cases. A 100% bulletproof solution on Windows is hard, because Windows has a shifting concept of what the home directory means.
If `user.home` isn't good enough for you I would suggest choosing a definition of `home directory` for windows and using it, getting the appropriate environment variable with `System.getenv(String)`.

Comment: Apache has an [excellent wrapper](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html) for `System.getProperty` calls that I recommend using. The correct call under that would be `SystemUtils.getUserHome()`.

Answer (score 173):

Actually with Java 8 the right way is to use:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

The bug  [JDK-6519127](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6519127) has been fixed and the "Incompatibilities between JDK 8 and JDK 7" section of the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) states:

> Area: Core Libs / java.lang
>
> Synopsis
>
> The steps used to determine the user's home directory on Windows have changed to follow the Microsoft recommended approach. This change
>   might be observable on older editions of Windows or where registry
>   settings or environment variables are set to other directories. Nature
>   of Incompatibility
>
> ```
> behavioral RFE
>
> 6519127
> ```

Despite the question being old I leave this for future reference.

Answer (score 43):

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()).

Comment: Nope, not a correct answer, this is the same one as above. Yes, I did not only read the JavaDocs, but I also tried it out on all platforms before asking this question! The answer is not so simple.

Comment: This might go horribly wrong on windows, where it will just take the parent of the desktop directory, which might be anywhere …

Answer (score 32):

The concept of a HOME directory seems to be a bit vague when it comes to Windows. If the [environment variables](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) (HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH/USERPROFILE) aren't enough, you may have to resort to using native functions via [JNI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx) allows you to retrieve special folders, like *My Documents* (CSIDL_PERSONAL) or *Local Settings\Application Data* (CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA).

Sample JNA code:

```
public class PrintAppDataDir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (com.sun.jna.Platform.isWindows()) {
            HWND hwndOwner = null;
            int nFolder = Shell32.CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA;
            HANDLE hToken = null;
            int dwFlags = Shell32.SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT;
            char[] pszPath = new char[Shell32.MAX_PATH];
            int hResult = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHGetFolderPath(hwndOwner, nFolder,
                    hToken, dwFlags, pszPath);
            if (Shell32.S_OK == hResult) {
                String path = new String(pszPath);
                int len = path.indexOf('\0');
                path = path.substring(0, len);
                System.out.println(path);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Error: " + hResult);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    static {
        OPTIONS.put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        OPTIONS.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER,
                W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
    }

    static class HANDLE extends PointerType implements NativeMapped {
    }

    static class HWND extends HANDLE {
    }

    static interface Shell32 extends Library {

        public static final int MAX_PATH = 260;
        public static final int CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 0x001c;
        public static final int SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
        public static final int SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT = 1;
        public static final int S_OK = 0;

        static Shell32 INSTANCE = (Shell32) Native.loadLibrary("shell32",
                Shell32.class, OPTIONS);

        /**
         * see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx
         * 
         * HRESULT SHGetFolderPath( HWND hwndOwner, int nFolder, HANDLE hToken,
         * DWORD dwFlags, LPTSTR pszPath);
         */
        public int SHGetFolderPath(HWND hwndOwner, int nFolder, HANDLE hToken,
                int dwFlags, char[] pszPath);

    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, the folder that corresponds to the user's home directory is CSIDL_PROFILE.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: Yes, this is an elaborate version for the Windows case.

Comment: In recent versions of JNA (more precisely jna-platform), there is a Shell32Util class which encapsulates the corresponding Windows API in a very nice way. In particular, using Shell32Util.getKnownFolderPath(...) in combination with one of the constants from the KnownFolders class should be appropriate. The older getFolderPath API function is deprecated since Windows Vista.

Answer (score 18):

Others have answered the question before me but a useful program to print out all available properties is:

```
for (Map.Entry<?,?> e : System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue())); 
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't depend on this, because not all properties are standardized. Instead check the JavaDoc for System.getProperties() to find out which properties are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: That may be true but it's still pretty useful for a newbie I would think! I'm not sure it deserves 2 downvotes :-(

Answer (score 15):

Alternative would be to use Apache CommonsIO `FileUtils.getUserDirectory()` instead of `System.getProperty("user.home")`. It will get you the same result and there is no chance to introduce a typo when specifying system property.

There is a big chance you already have Apache CommonsIO library in your project. Don't introduce it if you plan to use it only for getting user home directory.

Comment: `File FileUtils.getUserDirectory()` | `String FileUtils.getUserDirectoryPath()` - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 7):

As I was searching for Scala version, all I could find was McDowell's JNA code above.  I include my Scala port here, as there currently isn't anywhere more appropriate.

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32._
object jna {
    def getHome: java.io.File = {
        if (!com.sun.jna.Platform.isWindows()) {
            new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"))
        }
        else {
            val pszPath: Array[Char] = new Array[Char](WinDef.MAX_PATH)
            new java.io.File(Shell32.INSTANCE.SHGetSpecialFolderPath(null, pszPath, ShlObj.CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, false) match {
                case true => new String(pszPath.takeWhile(c => c != '\0'))
                case _    => System.getProperty("user.home")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

As with the Java version, you will need to add [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna), including both jar files, to your referenced libraries.

It's nice to see that JNA now makes this much easier than when the original code was posted.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the algorithm detailed in the bug report using System.getenv(String), and fallback to using the user.dir property if none of the environment variables indicated a valid existing directory.  This should work cross-platform.

I think, under Windows, what you are really after is the user's notional "documents" directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that works well on windows there is a package called [WinFoldersJava](https://github.com/catnapgames/WinFoldersJava) which wraps the native call to get the 'special' directories on Windows.  We use it frequently and it works well.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 | This is not the web page you are looking for"*