# What is the cross-platform way of obtaining the path to the local application data directory?

Tags: java, cross-platform

What I need is a platform-independent way of obtaining the path to the local application data directory. `System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")` seems to work only with Windows. How do I go about this?

Comment: Another problem is that other OSes don't even distinguish between local and roaming parts of the profile :-)

Comment: See also [*Create a temporary directory in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/617414/230513).

Comment: Voted to close the question, as I found an answer in the other thread.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could probably say something like (contradict me if I am wrong, or if this a bad approach)

```
private String workingDirectory;
//here, we assign the name of the OS, according to Java, to a variable...
private String OS = (System.getProperty("os.name")).toUpperCase();
//to determine what the workingDirectory is.
//if it is some version of Windows
if (OS.contains("WIN"))
{
    //it is simply the location of the "AppData" folder
    workingDirectory = System.getenv("AppData");
}
//Otherwise, we assume Linux or Mac
else
{
    //in either case, we would start in the user's home directory
    workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
    //if we are on a Mac, we are not done, we look for "Application Support"
    workingDirectory += "/Library/Application Support";
}
//we are now free to set the workingDirectory to the subdirectory that is our 
//folder.
```

Note that, in this code, I am taking full advantage that Java treats `'/'` the same as `'\\'` when dealing with directories. Windows uses `'\\'` as pathSeparator, but it is happy with `'/'`, too. (At least Windows 7 is.) It is also case-insensitive on it's environment variables; we could have just as easily said `workingDirectory = System.getenv("APPDATA");` and it would have worked just as well.

Comment: An important sidenote: saying `private final String workingDirectory = System.getenv("AppData") + File.separatorChar + ourFolder;` and then 
`private File dataFolder = new File("workingDirectory");` 
`System.out.println("Our dataFolder was " + ((dataFolder.mkdir()) ? "" : "not ") + "created successfully");` does NOT guarantee that the parent directory of `dataFolder` will be the `AppData` folder. //In my case, this was stored in `Roaming`.

Comment: Also, you might want to get yourself access to a Linux OS and test this code; Ubuntu is Linux, and I have no idea if `"user.home"` is a valid property on that OS; my experience with Linux doesn't include playing around on there. `//Happy coding, and you might want to accept an answer.`

Comment: In addition, you might get a `SecurityException` on some machines: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Apple advises not to hardcode the `Application Support` folder. E.g. your code would fail for sandboxed applications.

Comment: Then, I shall directly name other folder that is subfolder of `System.getProperty("user.home");` that would probably be the folder to be directly used by the app, right?

Comment: @MikeWarren I have tested that `"user.home"` property return `/home/username` as Windows does. And as a tip, use a directory that start with a dot if you wanna hide it as `user.home` is the user folder and normally program folder are hide (start with a dot).

Comment: @MikeWarren Nice approach! Why not simply say `workingDirectory = System.getenv("AppData")` and then test if it's null to change it to UNIX location?

Comment: Didn't think of that at the time. Man, my answer got popular!

Comment: got popular, but this answer has not been accepted yet? @MikeWarren

Comment: @z80crew can you cite a source for that?  Doesn't give me an idea where to put data for sandboxed applications.

Comment: @Andy From the [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html): `For example, whereas a non-sandboxed app might store files in ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle_id>, the sandboxed version of the same app does not have access to that directory`.

Comment: @z80crew wait a minute, can Java even run inside the OSX App Sandbox? (not to be confused with Java's own security sandboxing)

Comment: @Andy I don't know. Left Java behind since a very long time now.

Comment: @z80crew understandable!

Comment: IMO this answer is wrong in several ways. In addition to the Mac sandbox violation, it hardcodes the Mac path even on Linux, and on Windows it uses environment variables (which might be not present at all, or messed with by the user), instead of calling the documented OS APIs on each OS to get to special folders. This can and will fail in unusual but valid cases.

Answer (score 28):

Personally, I found [`appdirs`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.harawata/appdirs) to be very helpful for similar use-cases. It [has functions](https://github.com/harawata/appdirs#supported-directories) that locate different kinds of useful directories:

- `getUserDataDir`
- `getUserConfigDir`
- `getUserCacheDir`
- `getUserLogDir`
- `getSiteDataDir` ← looks like this is the one you need
- `getSiteConfigDir`

The locations it returns are more or less standard:

- On Unix it follows [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).
- On Windows it invokes [SHGetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx).
- On macOS it uses well-known hardcoded paths.

Answer (score 15):

The questing is old but I am missing an answer listing environment vars instead of some funny absolute paths. I do not know anything about OSX. this post only contains information about windows and linux.

I have not enough points to extend an already existing answer so I have to write a new one.

**Linux:**
As previously mentioned there exists something like freedesktop.org which is defining a standard the linux distributions are trying to fulfill.
There is also a subpage defining environment variables and their default values (If they are not set they are empty by default. The application has to match the variable to the default). Link to that page: [freedesktop.org env vars](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html)

**Vars defined relevant for this question:**

- **$XDG_DATA_HOME** (*local*) (defaults to: **$HOME/.local/share**)
- **$XDG_CONFIG_HOME** (*local*) (defaults to: **$HOME/.config**)
- **$XDG_DATA_DIRS** (*global*) (defaults to: **/usr/local/share/** or **/usr/share/**)
- **$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS** (*global*) (defaults to: **/etc/xdg**)

**Windows XP:**

- **%APPDATA%** (defaults to: **C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application Data**)
- **%CommonProgramFiles%** (defaults to: **C:\Program Files\Common Files**) (shared program files)
- **%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%** (defaults to: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files**) (64-bit only!) (shared program files)
- **%ProgramFiles%** (defaults to: **%SystemDrive%\Program Files**)
- **%ProgramFiles(x86)%** (defaults to: **%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)** (only in 64-bit version)) (64-bit only!)

**Windows Vista +:**

- **%APPDATA%** (defaults to: **C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming**) (Shared between linked workstations. User local. Save files and configs)
- **%LOCALAPPDATA%** (defaults to: **C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local**) (User local. Save files and configs)
- **%CommonProgramFiles%** (defaults to: **C:\Program Files\Common Files**) (shared program files)
- **%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%** (defaults to: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files**) (64-bit only!) (shared program files)
- **%ProgramFiles%** (defaults to: **%SystemDrive%\Program Files**) (Static data that will not change after installation)
- **%ProgramFiles(x86)%** (defaults to: **%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)** (only in 64-bit version)) (64-bit only!) (Static data that will not change after installation)
- **%ProgramData%** (defaults to: **%SystemDrive%\ProgramData**) (Changeable data affecting all users)

**In short:**
Linux has two environment variables which might not be set (one for configs, one for files). Windows has as far as I can tell only one environment var for configs and files together. Please use these instead of absolute paths.

Comment: Mac OS X locations are examined [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28928/20589).

Comment: Windows XP doesn't have the **%LOCALAPPDATA%** variable, but it has the folder, it's at **%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data**

Comment: SystemDrive\ProgramData seems having a protection if it's not admin access? @FjolnirDvorak?

Comment: @gumuruh yes. Every system wide or not user bound path needs permission elevation

Answer (score 8):

For moderate amounts of data, consider `java.util.prefs.Preferences`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481515/230513). It is cross-platform.

An erstwhile alternative, `javax.jnlp.PersistenceService`, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6886694/230513), is [now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46904795/230513).

Comment: @thrashgod could you provide an example of how to retrieve the local app data directory from `java.util.Preferences`?

Comment: Storing data directly in `Preferences` precludes the need to specify a [`workingDirectory`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16660314/230513), as `Preferences` already abstracts the location.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross platform way for that, because the concepts that the different OS-s use are too different to "abstract away". I am not familiar with *nix and Mac conventions, but on Windows there is no "home folder" and the application has to specify whether it wants to store stuff in the *roaming profile* (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<application vendor>\<application name>\` by default) or the *local profile* (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\<application vendor>\<application name>\` by default).

Note that you cannot hardcode these paths, because on a networked installation they might be somewhere else. You shouldn't rely on environment variables either because they can be modified by the user. Your application should call the [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function of the Windows API.

The difference between the two is that the local profile is specific to the user and the machine, while the roaming profile is specific to the user, so in a setup like my university, stuff apps put in the roaming profile are uploaded to the server and synced to whichever computer I log in to.

It should be the responsibility of applications to choose whether the settings they want to store are local or roaming. Unfortunately Java does not allow apps to decide this. Instead there is a global user-configurable setting that determines which folder you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

This is a culmination of various other StackOverflow answers alongside some ideas from the [appdata](https://github.com/harawata/appdirs) project, without introducing a dependency on [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). There is a dependency on [Apache Commons Lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), which can be eliminated by using return values from `System.getProperty( "os.name" )` as shown elsewhere.

## Code

Note that I haven't tested this on any platform except Linux:

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import static java.lang.System.getProperty;
import static java.lang.System.getenv;
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.*;

/**
 * Responsible for determining the directory to write application data, across
 * multiple platforms. See also:
 *
 * <ul>
 * <li>
 *   <a href="https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html">
 *     Linux: XDG Base Directory Specification
 *   </a>
 * </li>
 * <li>
 *   <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables">
 *     Windows: Recognized environment variables
 *   </a>
 * </li>
 * <li>
 *   <a href="https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html">
 *     MacOS: File System Programming Guide
 *   </a>
 * </li>
 * </ul>
 * </p>
 */
public final class UserDataDir {

  private static final Path UNDEFINED = Path.of( "/" );

  private static final String PROP_USER_HOME = getProperty( "user.home" );
  private static final String PROP_OS_VERSION = getProperty( "os.version" );
  private static final String ENV_APPDATA = getenv( "AppData" );
  private static final String ENV_XDG_DATA_HOME = getenv( "XDG_DATA_HOME" );

  private UserDataDir() { }

  public static Path getAppPath( final String appName )
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    final var osPath = isWindows()
      ? getWinAppPath()
      : isMacOs()
      ? getMacAppPath()
      : isUnix()
      ? getUnixAppPath()
      : UNDEFINED;

    final var path = osPath.equals( UNDEFINED )
      ? getDefaultAppPath( appName )
      : osPath.resolve( appName );

    return ensureExists( path ) ? path : fail( path );
  }

  private static Path fail( final Path path ) throws FileNotFoundException {
    throw new FileNotFoundException( path.toString() );
  }

  private static Path getWinAppPath() {
    return ENV_APPDATA == null || ENV_APPDATA.isBlank()
      ? home( getWinVerAppPath() )
      : Path.of( ENV_APPDATA );
  }

  /**
   * Gets the application path with respect to the Windows version.
   *
   * @return The directory name paths relative to the user's home directory.
   */
  private static String[] getWinVerAppPath() {
    return PROP_OS_VERSION.startsWith( "5." )
      ? new String[]{"Application Data"}
      : new String[]{"AppData", "Roaming"};
  }

  private static Path getMacAppPath() {
    final var path = home( "Library", "Application Support" );

    return ensureExists( path ) ? path : UNDEFINED;
  }

  private static Path getUnixAppPath() {
    // Fallback in case the XDG data directory is undefined.
    var path = home( ".local", "share" );

    if( ENV_XDG_DATA_HOME != null && !ENV_XDG_DATA_HOME.isBlank() ) {
      final var xdgPath = Path.of( ENV_XDG_DATA_HOME );

      path = ensureExists( xdgPath ) ? xdgPath : path;
    }

    return path;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a hidden directory relative to the user's home directory.
   *
   * @param appName The application name.
   * @return A suitable directory for storing application files.
   */
  private static Path getDefaultAppPath( final String appName ) {
    return home( '.' + appName );
  }

  private static Path home( final String... paths ) {
    return Path.of( PROP_USER_HOME, paths );
  }

  /**
   * Verifies whether the path exists or was created.
   *
   * @param path The directory to verify.
   * @return {@code true} if the path already exists or was created,
   * {@code false} if the directory doesn't exist and couldn't be created.
   */
  private static boolean ensureExists( final Path path ) {
    final var file = path.toFile();
    return file.exists() || file.mkdirs();
  }

  private static boolean isWindows() {
    return IS_OS_WINDOWS;
  }

  private static boolean isMacOs() {
    return IS_OS_MAC;
  }

  private static boolean isUnix() {
    return IS_OS_UNIX;
  }
}
```

## Test

A unit test to show usage:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class UserDataDirTest {
  @Test
  void test_Unix_GetAppDirectory_DirectoryExists()
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    final var path = UserDataDir.getAppPath( "test" );
    final var file = path.toFile();

    assertTrue( file.exists() );
    assertTrue( file.delete() );
    assertFalse( file.exists() );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use this

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

or this:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

I prefer the first option

Regards

Comment: I believe you meant "user.home". "user.dir" is the current working directory, which is not guaranteed to be where the AppData folder is located