# Customizable Shortcuts in Java Application

Tags: java, swing, shortcut, hotkeys, jide

I would like to include customizable keyboard shortcuts in my Java application (the user can change them). Since this is not very unusual request, I was wondering if there exists a library/project that could help me achieve my goal.

Unfortunately I was not able to find anything useful on Google.

Thank you,
aZen

---

Ended up building my own shortcut manager from scratch. This took around 20h.

Comment: I'm using JIDE (so yes). They have a solution, but it is not included in their Professional Suite and the Ultimate Suite is rather expensive.

Comment: I have edited your tags to make them more relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcuts may be specified as accelerators in instances of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). Less flexibly, shortcuts may be represented by `KeyEvent` instances obtained via `KeyListener`. Either may be stored in `java.util.Preferences` or `javax.jnlp.BasicService`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114200/230513).

I'm unaware of a general purpose library, but this [game](https://sourceforge.net/projects/robotchase/) offers an `RCKeys` dialog to remap keys. It includes the essential functionality to preclude duplicates.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any libraries, but if your stuck you should take a look at [KeyboardFocusManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html) & [KeyboardEventDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html) or [KeyboardEventPostProcessor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventPostProcessor.html).

These will at least give you access to the system level key events

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I know about these classes but was hoping for some kind of plug-and-play component.