# Java Mac OS X implementing a mac like preferences dialog

Tags: java, macos, swing

I am somewhat new to Java, and new to OS X programming.  I have worked my way through several of the details of getting a Java app to look like a native Mac app.  Now I am struggling with implementing a preferences dialog that looks "mac like".

I am working on Mountain Lion and Java SE 6.  Is there a simple solution to this, or is it just working with JDialog and JToolbar, et. Al.?

Thank you
Tim

Comment: see [Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: See also [*Mac Widgets for Java*](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/).

Answer (score 4):

Several things are worth noting in this regard:

- Don't override the default [Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html), `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.
- Do create a Mac applicaiton bundle, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).
- Do consider libraries such as [*Mac Widgets for Java*](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/).
- Use `java.util.Preferences` or `javax.jnlp.BasicService`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724866/230513).

Comment: Or, _do_ override the default Look & Feel. Literally.

Comment: @Trejkaz: Good point; the *Mac Widgets for Java* is an example.