# Doing Different Actions Based On Customizable Keybindings

Tags: java, oop, key-bindings

I need to take in customizable actions read from a file and bind them to a key for a program.

If I have a file like so:

```
w:up
s:down
a:left
d:right
```

How would I go about getting this running?

The only way I see it is doing this:

```
// hardcoded String to Action to turn "up" into an actual instruction
HashMap<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<String, Action();
actions.put("up", new Up());
actions.put("down", new Down()); // etc.


HashMap<Integer, Action> keybindings = new HashMap<Integer, Action>();
while (!endOfFile) {
    int key = letterToKeycode(getKey()); // gets keycode for letter
    Action action = actions.get(getCommand());
    keybindings.put(key, action);
    endOfFile = isEndOfFile();
}
```

Then when my keylistener method gets called, it does:

```
public void keyPressed(int keycode) {
    keybindings.get(keycode).doAction();
}
```

and `doAction()` would be in each `Action` class. So if I had `Up()`, it would call `person.moveUp()`.

If I was to rebind most of my keys, it could result in hundreds of classes that are a few lines long.

There's something about the above concept, and a single switch statement that makes me want to avoid them. Is there "cleaner" trick to doing this?

As an example of what I mean, Eclipse has keybindings you can set in the preferences, so when you hit a key, it fires off an event and interprets what the key is supposed to do based on those settings. I'm attempting to do this.

Comment: See also [`LinePanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513).

Comment: After following the [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) link from the answer that @trashgod linked to, it seems that Swing uses a very similar technique in regards to the original solution I suggested in my answer, that I wanted to improve. Since Swing uses this method, I am under the impression that it is likely the most straight forward way of tackling this. Guess that means, no, there really isn't much of a way to do this better.

Comment: The example cited does not use `switch`. You may be able to parameterize or re-factor your `Action` implementation(s) to mitigate proliferation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create your own `Map`, use [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html); [`LinePanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797965/230513) is an example. You may be able to parameterize or re-factor your `Action` implementation(s) to mitigate proliferation. To persist user-defined key assignments, you may be able to adapt the approach used in the example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724866/230513).