# function keys on mac os x in java swing application

Tags: java, macos, swing

I have a java swing app that has some shortcuts key (`F10`,`F12`, etc). 
The problem is that when I run this app on MacOS X the shortcuts keys when are pressed they have the default behavior on mac OS.

It is some possibility to disable the default behavior of the F keys on MacOS programmatically from my swing app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these settings are under the user's aegis in `System preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts`. Of course, nothing precludes your adding a modifier to your chosen [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513). Ideally, you should let the user [persist a preference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114200/230513).