# Is there a widget for making configurable toolbar in java

Tags: java, swing, toolbar, jtoolbar

Is there a widget for making configurable toolbar in java ?

Couldnt find anything in swingx but seems a common problem

Comment: What do you mean by "configurable"?  Best to explain why [`javax.swing.JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) isn't suitable for you.

Comment: @Dave Webb JToolBar is fine, but I mean is I need to create a dialog to allow user to modify the toobar, add/remove tasks, change shortcut keys, icons ecetera.

Comment: just ... do it? Can't see much of a wide-spread need for such a dialog ...

Comment: "seems a common problem" really ? You could enhance your question with externals links/resources.

Comment: I am just just doing it, but I dont understand why no ones sees a need, most applications allow you to full configure a toolbar these days. I just checked some applications on my mac - Thunderbird, Firefox, Preview, IntelliJ,

Comment: @gonard I can't find any resources, that was the question !

Comment: cool - once you did it, you might consider contributing to SwingX :-)

Comment: @kleopatra sure, I've contributed a couple of minor things in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instances of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to expose your application's functionality. Add these actions to your toolbar buttons. Because `JToolBar` is a `Container` you can `add()` and `remove()` buttons as needed in your toolbar editor by invoking `revalidate()` and `repaint()`. You can persist the current settings as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11114200/230513).

Comment: Thanks, yes that is along the same lines of what Im doing

Comment: I usually just go for a basic editor with check boxes; [*Arachnophilia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnophilia) has an interesting interface; at the high end, [`JHotDraw`](http://www.jhotdraw.org/) configures the toolbars dynamically based on context.