# to run class file inside jar, along with properties file which is in different directory from command prompt

Tags: java, command-line, jar

1)I have jar file named abc.jar. 
2) There is a class file def.class inside abc.jar which has main method and I want to run this class. This class is under package gog.com.custom 
3) This class refers a property file xyz.properties which is outside this abc.jar

How can I run def.class along with xyz.properties from command line ?

Comment: You need to specify the `Main-Class` attribute in the .jar file’s manifest.  As for reading a properties file, answering that requires seeing the code which attempts to read it.  If the properties file is read-only, place it inside the .jar;  if it is not read-only, put it in a known location like the user’s home directory or the [user’s configuration directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder).

Comment: Hi, I was manage to run it. def.class already has main method. I was able to resolve the issue java -classpath .;abc.jar;xyz.properties com.aps.pi.def