# Writing to properties file from .jar executable

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, properties, executable

I have a problem with writing to properties file via .jar file. 
My 'output' works only in Eclipse, but don't know how to change it and make it works in executable .jar.

```
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("src/application/data.properties",true);
        InputStream in = Login.class.getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
        properties.load(in);

        properties.setProperty(username+"Username", username);
        properties.setProperty(username+"Password", password);
        properties.store(output, formattedDate);
```

**EDIT:**

I'm getting no errors. I want to store this 'username' and 'password' in data.properties file which is included in a project. When I run it in Eclipse, it works. When I run it by .jar file, it doesn't write those data to properties file. I suppose, it's because when it creates 'output' while running jar, it is created only locally, and it doesn't provide me the access to appropriate file, but I might be wrong. I get this access and I can work on this existing file when I create 'in' by .getResourceAsStream(), but don't know how create 'output' in a similiar way, and be able to store data in already existing file in project.
I create .jar in eclipse by "Export -> runnable JAR file " and run it by double-click.

Comment: You don't provide sufficient informations. What are you getting? What do you want? How do you create this jar? How do you run it? We can't guess.

Comment: When it's running as a jar in a different locaion, the folders "src/application" probably won't exist.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm getting no errors.

Comment: When you run from a .jar file, your development project is not visible and effectively does not exist.  Use the data.properties in your .jar file as a *prototype* for a *brand new* data.properties stored somewhere under the user’s home directory.  See https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'll risk a guess: `getResourceAsStream` is returning a Stream reading the properties file **inside** the JAR, while `FileOutputStream` is addressing a file **outside** the JAR - the properties inside the JAR is never changed!

   It is not trivial to overwrite a file inside a (running) JAR! The Jar must be recreated for that. Probably better only write/read from an external file, that is, use `FileInputStream` instead of `getResourceAsStream`. It's also a bit strange to access a file in the "src" directory since this normally is not included in the deployed system/code.
2. Using `FileOutputStream(..., true)` is appending the data to the end of file - it is not overwriting the data for an existing user. Not sure if that is a problem or if this code is only called for new users?!
3. saving clear passwords (file or database) is a potential security threat...