# Application packaged with Jlink cannot find properties file

Tags: java, properties-file, jlink

I am migrating an application from Oracle Java 8 to openJDK11 + openJFX11.
In the Java 8 version, I loaded a properties file using the following code (CryoStats is the class containing the code):

```
try {
    jarLocation = CryoStats.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
    confLocation = jarLocation.substring(0, jarLocation.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/config/";
try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(confLocation + "CryoStats.properties");) {
            properties.load(input);
            HORUS_HOST = properties.getProperty("HORUS_HOST");
            HORUS_USERNAME = properties.getProperty("HORUS_USERNAME");
            HORUS_PASSWORD = properties.getProperty("HORUS_PASSWORD");
            CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("CONNECTION_TIMEOUT"));
            SOCKET_TIMEOUT = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("SOCKET_TIMEOUT"));
            System.out.println("CryoStats.properties loaded.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error loading properties file");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error loading properties file");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

In my Netbeans build configuration, I had a task that copied the "config" folder to the "dist" folder, which therefore included: my jar file, a "lib" folder, a "config" folder.
This code worked both within Netbeans and at run-time.

I need to give the user the possibility to edit the properties file, so I need to keep it outside of the jar.

I have now migrated the code to an Eclipse project, and I compile against openJDK11 and openJFX11. If I run the project within Eclipse, it loads the properties file. However, if I create a run-time image of my module with jlink, it can't find the properties file and the value of jarLocation is:

```
jarLocation = /cryostats
```

To the best of my knowledge, this happens because there is no concept of a class-path within a fully-modular Java application, so as a workaround, I have used

```
confLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/config/";
```

and I have manually copied the "config" folder to the "bin" folder after executing jlink. This works when I launch the application but it doesn't work from within Eclipse, and it's a crude and ugly solution.

Is there a way to keep the properties file accessible by the user within the run-time image generated by jlink and at the same time accessible by Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has never been correct to assume classes come from a .jar file which is a physical file in the platform’s file system.  (Also, [getCodeSource() can return null](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource())).

Windows, OS X, and Linux all have standard locations where user configuration files are stored.  See [Find place for dedicated application folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder).  To oversimplify the information from that link:

- Windows: `System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\CryoStats"`
- OS X: `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/CryoStats"`
- Linux: `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.config/CryoStats"`

(Don’t just use those paths directly;  it’s actually more complicated than this.  Read the link for the full explanation.)

Never use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`—that’s the current directory, and it could be anything, including the system’s root directory.  On the other hand, the `user.home` system property points to a stable location, namely the user’s home directory.

What I do for application configuration is:  I include the *default* configuration inside the program, as a read-only resource.  When the program exits, it saves that configuration, possibly modified by the user, to the system’s standard configuration location.

Comment: Hi, may I know how you handle switching between default configuration as read-only and then later switch to system's standard configuration location?

Comment: @SukmaWardana If the standard configuration file exists, I read it;  otherwise, I fall back to using the default configuration.