# Access system property in java .properties file

Tags: java, properties, system-properties

I'm trying to access System property variable in java properties file. I'm not in the position to use other java class.

I want to define a property for a working directory(say `work.dir=/home/username/working-directory`), for my production `.properties` file, without hard-coding the `/home/username`.  I want to reference the system property user.home in place on the hard-coded `/home/username`, to make `work.dir` more generic.

Comment: Neither the properties file format nor the Properties class has any native support for that. But nothing forbids you to use something like {user.home}/working-directory, and to replace {user.home} by the value of the user.home System property.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not clear when you said nothing forbids me to use {user.home}/working-directory. This is calling system property if I am correct

Comment: No. Read my comment again. Nothing will replace {user.home} (or any other convention you choose) by /home/username. You need to do that by yourself.

Comment: If you're fine with build-time interpolation and you're using Maven, have a look at [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Don't know what your exact use case is, so I'm not sure if it works for you.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder

Answer (score 0):

This will be used to get the system variable -

```
System.getenv("EnviromentVariable");
```

and the above value you can set the java Properties key.

Alternate way, you can run the jar

```
java -jar jarName -DpropertyName=value
System.getProperty("propertyName"); // you can set this value in java properties.
```