# Database not working when running jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

i created an application in java 16 using javafx and used sqlite embedded database when i create jar file using intellij it works fine from inside intellij as shown in picture (the username and password are stored in the database i try to connect to ):
[image]

but when i open it without intellij it executes but doesn't connect to database:
[image]

Here is the code that executes the login button:

```
public void login(ActionEvent event ) throws IOException {
        String username = textInput.getText();
        String password = passwordInput.getText();

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:packApp/src/sample/DataBase/sqlite.db";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+username+"' and password = '"+password+"'";
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

/*some other code...*/
```

Here is the error code when i try pressing "login button" in my application which i executed using cmd (java -jar packApp.jar):

```
C:\Users\Kazan\Documents\GitHub\packApp\out\artifacts\packApp_jar>java -jar packApp.jar
Jun 11, 2021 9:16:08 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2b67781'
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'packApp/src/sample/DataBase/sqlite.db': 'C:\Users\Kazan\Documents\GitHub\packApp\out\artifacts\packApp_jar\packApp' does not exist
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:61)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:28)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:21)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:115)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:90)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
        at sample.packapp.loginPage.rootPageController.login(rootPageController.java:83)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Is there any solution i have to try ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite JDBC driver requires a path to an actual file.

The entries in a .jar file are not files.  They are just parts of the .jar file.

You must provide an actual file to the sqlite driver, not an entry in an archive.  One way to do that is to copy your embedded resource to a temporary file:

```
Path dbFile = Files.createTempFile(null, ".db");
try (InputStream embeddedDB =
        rootPageController.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "/sample/DataBase/sqlite.db")) {
    Files.copy(embeddedDB, dbFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFile;
```

Comment: This is working, the only problem is that these lines of code generate a temporary database, so whenever I try to modify the database using my application it doesn't do any effect what is the solution to that?

Comment: @AnasCHAHID Instead of a temporary file, use a [known location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder). If that file exists, don’t copy your resource over it at all.