# regarding java file system?

Tags: java, serialization, filesystems

I am new to the java file system.I store the serializable object in some file location for example d:\my files\file.txt(location is hardcoded).what should I do so that it will work on all the platforms(Linux, Windows, and UNIX).Thanks in advance

Comment: You could make it user-configurable.

Comment: For long-term storage of application data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save files related to the program, you could use a relative path and `'/'` should work as a path separator across all platforms.

If for some reason you definitely want absolute paths, you'll need to detect system os using `System.getProperty("os.name")`  refer https://www.baeldung.com/java-detect-os and you can store os specific hard coded paths like

```
HashMap<String, String> osPathMap= new HashMap<>();
osPathMap.put("Windows 10", "d:\my files\file.txt");
osPathMap.put("Linux", "Some linux path");
```

and get the path using `osPathMap.get(os_name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty` with the parameters : `user.dir` or `user.home`  , they give you the working directory path and the user home directory path on String format independently with the OS :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // print the path of the working directory
         System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
         // print the path of the user directory 
         System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
}
```