# Why does a folder created by an application in /var directory on Unix gets deleted on application restart?

Tags: java, unix

Why does a folder created by an application in /var directory on Unix gets deleted on application restart ?

My app creates a folder in side var directory and write a file to it as /var/myAppName/.txt.. but on appp restart th is folder is deleted and I loose the file

Where to write so that folder is not deleted

Comment: Maybe you can check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared)
Some system will delete temp dir after reboot.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example as explained in the help center page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It is not clear how the application is creating and using the file.

Comment: Create off (system property) `user.home`

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388882/find-place-for-dedicated-application-folder useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to point the folder to your user default folder like /home/userName/yourAppName .

you can get this path using `echo $HOME` at your unix terminal