# Java Jar: Executing a method only upon opening the jar for the first time?

Tags: java

I want a "welcome" dialogue box to appear -- but only the first time the application is opened. Do I need some sort of text file in my JAR which "remembers" if the dialogue has already appeared? Is there a more elegant way of doing it than this?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I do want it as OS-indepedent as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Preferences API is how I did something like this. It will store a value in the Registry (Windows) or user's home folder or UNIX, so it works on everything.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

There is not really any more elegant way of doing that, as you can't manage that kind of behavior directly in your code (directly in your jar). Saving it to a hidden file for example could be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the best approach is probably OS dependent, ie writing to the application data [folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198911/how-to-get-local-application-data-folder-in-java) in Windows and writing to a hidden folder in the home directory in *nix systems. You can use the preferences [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for the actual preferences implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Does the app. have a GUI?  If so, launch it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & use the [`SingleInstanceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html) of the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) API to show the '"welcome" dialogue box'.

The SIS will invoke custom code the first time an application is run.  See this small [demo. of the `SingleInstanceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis) for more details, the code is available for download.