# How do I get the value of Windows' %APPDATA% location variable in Java?

Tags: java, windows, variables, appdata

I'm trying to make my program save its state in the location set by `%APPDATA%` when the user is using Windows. However, `System.getProperty("temp.dir");` does not return that. **How do I get the value of the `%APPDATA%` variable in Windows, for the purpose of state saving?**

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198911/how-to-get-local-application-data-folder-in-java

Comment: Better duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use System.getenv()

```
System.getenv("APPDATA")
```

But I think

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

should be preferred even though it's not *exactly* the same thing because it is more portable.

Comment: What happens if you try `System.getenv("APPDATA")` on a non-Windows OS? Given that `APPDATA` is Windows-specific, I would imagine that some error occurs.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: if you are trying to get the best native integration with the environment then using the "user.home" property is a poor substitute to (Windows) APPDATA or (Free Desktop) XDG_DATA_HOME XDG_CONFG_HOME

Answer (score 9):

APPDATA is a Windows specific environment variable that gives you the location where application specific data is stored, so if you are not looking to write platform independent code, you can just do `System.getenv("APPDATA");`