# I want to find a value from an array

Tags: java, arrays

Here's my java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;



public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        File[] files = new File("%appdata%").listFiles();
        showFiles(files);
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( files ) );
        if (Arrays.asList(files).contains(".minecraft")) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
    }

    public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
    }

}
```

I want code above to check if .minecraft folder exists in %appdata%. I am total N00B to Java. I have worked with PHP, but doesn't seem to help me :) Please help, it annoys me.

-Simon

Comment: Start with [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) tutorial.

Comment: Please don't give negative votes to person who has shown what he did till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in finding only the ".minecraft" file it would be much easier to:

```
File appdata = new File("%appdata%");
File minecraft = new File(appdata, ".minecraft");
if (minecraft.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

EDIT: Based on comment, (and I'm a linux guy mostly), you need to use the correct `%APPDATA%` location: [How do I get the value of Windows' %APPDATA% location variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235734/how-to-get-the-value-of-windows-appdata-location-variable-in-java)

Comment: Here's my new code: `public class mainClass {

 File appdata = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA"));
 File minecraft = new File(appdata, ".minecraft");
 if (minecraft.exists()) {
     System.out.println("Success");
 }

}` But it is giving my this error: **Error: Main method not found in class mainClass, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.minecraft`is a **hidden folder**. You need to access the folder like this:

```
File directory = new File("%appdata%");    
File[] hiddenFiles = directory.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.HIDDEN);
for (File hiddenFile: hiddenFiles) {
    System.out.println("hidden file: " + hiddenFile.getCanonicalPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As rolfl mentioned, there is a better way to look for a single file.

That said, your code isn't performing a proper check.  You are creating an array of `File` objects, converting the array to a `List`, and then checking the list for a `String` value.  The `String` value will never match a `File` object.

If you want to find a single file, use rolfl's answer.  If you want to fix your code specifically, here's something to get your started:

- You need to iterate over the list of files.  What do you gain by converting to a `List`?
- You need to find a way to match a `File's` name with a `String` name.  What method might you call on the `File` object to get its name?
- You need to do a `String` comparison between the `File's` name and `".minecraft"`.  What might that comparison look like?

Please note: reference L.Butz answer as well; I haven't accessed hidden files in Java, so it's possible there's an extra step you need to get access to them.

Answer (score 0):

`%appdata%`is an environment variable and as such it will not be automatically resolved by [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). So you need to resolve it before listing it. This is done using [System#getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29)

```
@Test
public void dirExistsInAppData() {
    Assert.assertTrue(dirExistsInAppData(".minecraft"));
}

private boolean dirExistsInAppData(final String dirname) {
    File dir = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA"), dirname);
    return dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory();
}
```