# How can I set a filepath in java by using Environmental Variables from windows?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a new file inside of the appdata directory, but none of the environmental varibles that I am using with the classpath are working.

I want this program to be runnable on more than just my local machine, so I dont want to hardcode the values in there, which is why I am using these variables.

If I try the command

`FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("%HOMEDRIVE%//chromedriver.exe"));`

or

`FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("%AppData%\\Local\\Temp"));`

Both of them give the error

`%HOMEDRIVE%\chromedriver.exe (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Any advice?

Comment: You can retrieve dinamically the path to appdata using `System.getenv("APPDATA")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of Windows' %APPDATA% location variable in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235734/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-windows-appdata-location-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `java.io.tmpdir` like,

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
```

Another option, is to use [`File.createTempFile(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which will create a temporary file in the system temp directory. If you just want to access an environment variable, you can do that with something like

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"));
```

(if you want to access `%HOMEDRIVE%`). Note: On *nix-like systems, the above would access the environment variable `$HOMEDRIVE`.