# OS-independent location to store program files

Tags: java, file-location

I'm looking for a platform-independent way of getting a location where my Java program can save files. This location should be user-dependent.

What I want is:

- `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\MyAppName\` on Windows,
- `~/.local/share/MyAppName/` or something like that on Ubuntu
- Anything else corresponting so it works on every platform

Comment: Why don't you pick any location inside your application directory?

Comment: And what would my application directory be? How do I get it?

Comment: When a java class runs it by default creates a file at the same path where the class file is located.

Comment: And when running from a JAR?

Comment: @JunedAhsan On most newer versions of Windows (> Vista, I think), the user doesn't have write privileges to the program's folder. (In a lot of setups)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198911/how-to-get-local-application-data-folder-in-java

Comment: I tend to use a subdirectory of the user home folder myself. The most successful and flexible solution of all: make your application ask the user where to put stuff.

Comment: @Gimby I think I'll do that...