# How to select "My Documents" path to save a file

Tags: java, file, path, save, jfilechooser

I want to do that:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty(**MY DOCUMENTS PATH **)));
```

All I want to do is to put the "My Documents" path, that it changes in different windows versions, but I don't know how to do it.

I can't use a "literal path" I need a relative path because this application is going to work on all windows versions and I can't use literal paths.

Comment: Where is the "My Documents" path on linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting My Documents path in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677692/getting-my-documents-path-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far as I know this is the "my document" path for all windows versions:

```
String myDocumentPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "Documents";
```