# How to create folder in a directory not in working directory

Tags: java, directory

I am trying to create folder in /Users/Documents. I am using following code:

```
new File("/Users/Documents/myfolder");
```

But it is creating `/Users/Documents/myfolder` in my working directory.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't believe you. Also, instantiating a `File` does not create any directories.

Comment: @sudip saha use full path or read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677692/getting-my-documents-path-in-java

Comment: Please provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: You can't make a folder by new File(). You need to do: .mkdirs(); at the end of the new File()

Comment: `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents/My Brand new Folder").mkdirs()` ... but I'd also look at the return value to make sure it worked, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059085/how-can-i-create-a-file-in-the-current-users-home-directory-using-java/21059316#21059316) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mkdir` or `mkdirs` method from `File` to create directory.

```
File directory = new File("/Users/Documents/myfolder");
if (!directory.exists()) {
   directory.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone. Using Path instance solved this problem.