# Java System.properties for windows 8 get logged in user

Tags: java, windows

So I'm using the java System.getProperties("user.home"). Here's the problem I am encountering, I'm calling it in an installation process which required admin rights, and during the installation process I need to save a few files in the user's directory (ex. c:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\SavedFiles). The problem arises as shown in the steps below:

1) User mbrando logs in on windows 8 
2) He run's the installer
3) he is prompted to login with admin rights
4) he logs in as user: imadmin 
5) installer continues
6) installer saves some files that is local to the user in c:\users\imadmin\AppData... 
instead of c:\users\mbrando\AppData

The user's local home directory is obtained by calling the System.getProperties("user.home"). Basically I am wondering id I can get the logged in user's home directory rather than the admin user's. Any ideas how I can get this using the java System.getProperties?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows is a multi-user system. What if some other user runs the application? Consider doing this setup when the application is run first time. Also note the [issues with `user.home` on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534) - it may not point to anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The installer is run by "imadmin" actually. not mbrando.

Comment: Yeah, that is what's happening. But is it possible to get the other user's information (such as his home directory or even user name)?