# Java - using System.getProperty("user.dir") to get the home directory

Tags: java

I was wondering if using:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

to get the absolute path of a folder is the best way to go about it? I am looking to pass my application onto other computers and I need a full proof way of getting the 'home' directory so that I can just add onto the path when I need to use other folders by just doing:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String otherFolder = path + "\\other";
```

Comment: The root folder is "/". What are you trying to do?

Comment: "user.dir" is the current working directory, not the home directory

Comment: You seem to be mixing concepts here.  `user.dir` is the current directory.  The "absolute path" of a `File` object is obtained by `getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: Once your title is fixed to express what you're really asking, the question becomes nonsensical. `System.getProperty("user.dir")` is not way to get the home directory at all, it is the way to get the current working directory. -1 for causing yourself confusion.

Comment: Sorry, not what I meant I guess. Just meant the working directory. Wrong choice of words :S

Comment: The question title and actual content is not related.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java for user.home

Answer (score 57):

way of getting home directory of current user is

```
String currentUsersHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

and to append path separator

```
String otherFolder = currentUsersHomeDir + File.separator + "other";
```

[`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

> The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience. This string contains a single character, namely separatorChar.

Comment: It's "fool-proof", not "full proof"; and no I did not downvote.

Comment: See "JDK-4787931 : System property "user.home" does not correspond to "USERPROFILE" (win)"  mentioned in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java

Comment: it has been resolved already @Jay

Answer (score 8):

"user.dir" is the current working directory, not the home directory
It is all described here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Also, by using `\\` instead of File.separator, you will lose portability with *nix system which uses `/` for file separator.

Comment: Use File.separator for best cross platform or '/'.  The '/' works in Java even on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I never knew that '/' also works in Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Program to get the current working directory=user.dir

```
public class CurrentDirectoryExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String current = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + current);
    }
}
```