# Get project directory from java classes

Tags: java

I have a problem with `System.getProperty("user.dir")` giving different directory when run by IDE and when I manually compile & run it in cmd. My thing is this, I have project structure like this:

```
project
- exports
- src
  - main
    - java
      - Main
- file1
- file2
```

One of the `args` in `main` method is the name of one of those 2 files, that I then access.

When I configure my run in **IDE** it works like a charm - the directory I get is `C:\Users\**\**\**\project` and it is able to read and write to the file.

But when I compile it in **cmd** `javac Main.java` and then run it, I get `C:\Users\**\**\**\project\src\main\java` and because of that, I am unable to access the file without having to modify the *path*.

My question is, is there like a golden way, that would work for both these cases, without me having to alter the returned path?

**EDIT:**

For clear understanding, I know what `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns, but my question was, if it is possible to get the same result somehow with using `Path` or if I have to get the path and edit it, so that it will end in *project directory*?

**in IDE** I get: `C:\Users\petri\Desktop\CZM\bicycle-statistics`

**in cmd**: `C:\Users\petri\Desktop\CZM\bicycle-statistics\src\main\java`

I want to get the same path in cmd, that I got in IDE.

I tried using `Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()`, but it is the same thing.

So, what I did is this:

```
Path path = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();
while (!path.endsWith("project")) {
    path = path.getParent();
}
```

And it works, but I am trying to ask, if there is some more elegant way, because I will have to defend my solution in front of my supervisor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - using System.getProperty("user.dir") to get the home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709769/java-using-system-getpropertyuser-dir-to-get-the-home-directory)

Comment: `C:\Users\..\..\..\project` are the `..` segments literally two dots, or just stand for some other directory name?  If they are literal, that resolves to `C:\project`.

Comment: @JimGarrison they are normal folder names,like e.g. `Documents`

Comment: Please don't use `..` to represent literal directory names.  `..` means something specific in a path, and using that particular set of characters gives the wrong idea.  I'd suggest that you use `C:\Users\**\**\foo\bar` or something like that instead.  Anything but `..`.

Comment: My recommendation is that you never rely on the result of `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, or any other path that requires particular behavior outside of your code.  IMO, there are only two good ways to find a particular file: 1) in relation to a known location, like in the classpath, or in the current user's home directory, or 2) via a passed in **absolute** path.  Just my $.02, but I've been doing this a long time, and trying to use the current working directory or the value of a system property or environment variable you didn't set explicitly is just asking for trouble.

Comment: ...in case it isn't clear, I fully support the use of `System.getProperty("user.home")`, as that is a known location that does not change based on how and where a program is executed.

Comment: Alright, thank you all for your time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The project directory is not important.  Consider that, at runtime, you do not know how your project is being executed.  It could be from a directory in a filesystem, from a .jar file, or even from a jar transmitted over a network. There might not even be a filesystem under you.  The ONLY thing you can refer to is the base resource path defined by your class loader.

Comment: @JimGarrison ok, that's just outside of my knowledge reach, I think I have to look into JVM more to understand this, but still, thank you for your time, sir.

Comment: You can refer to things in the filesystem, _if there is a filesystem_, but things like `user.dir` and `user.home` may be totally unrelated to what you can actually access.  You can reliably access something relative to the class loader, or , as @CryptoFool says, only an absolute path, passed in via some mechanism (provided as input or on the command line).  What you can't ever assume, if you want your code to be bullet-proof, is that there is a "current directory".

Answer (score 1):

Normally your IDE will build source files in `src/main/java` and write the class files out to some other directory, like `target/classes`.

If your IDE built the project that way, then you can run it from the command line by switching to your project directory (`cd C:\Users\**\**\**\project` using your example) and then running:

```
java -classpath target/classes Main
```

assuming that `target/classes` is where your IDE put the files. If you really do have the class files in the source directory, then use `-classpath src/main/java`.

If you always run the program from the project directory, then you can assume within the program that the current directory is the project directory. You don't even have to use `user.dir` then, just use relative path names for everything, e.g., `path/to/whatever.dat` will automatically resolve to `C:\Users\**\**\**\project\path\to\whatever.dat`.

Comment: Thank you, but in my IDE it works just fine, my problem is when I run it in cmd it return the directory that my `Main` class is located in, rather than returning the project directory.

Comment: Right. My point is, don't run it from the directory containing `Main`, run it from the project directory, and use `-classpath` to tell Java where the classes are.

Answer (score 1):

> One of the args in main method is the name of one of those 2 files

Then make sure you enter the name correctly.

E.g. if the current working directory is the `project` folder, then name `file1` will refer to the `file1` file. If the current working directory is the `java` folder, then the argument to the program needs to be `..\..\..\file1`.

That is because you give **relative** file names, which means they are relative to the current working directory.

Alternatively, give a fully qualified name, then the argument will be the same, regardless of what the current working directory is:

`C:\Users\**\**\**\project\file1`

Comment: Yes, I actually did that, but the problem is when I share my work with my "supervisor" and he tries to run it in his workplace. That's why I am asking if it is possible to obtain the absolute path in a particular way, or if I have to alter the path.

Comment: Drop a script into your project directory that runs your program with the classpath (described in my answer) and tell your supervisor to run that.

Comment: @AP11 When you supervisor runs the code, (s)he should know how working directories work, and correctly qualify the file name, depending on how the code is executed. If supervisor doesn't even know how working directories function, then you shouldn't be giving the supervisor source code, but a runnable jar, and the with the jar and file right next to each other, running the program will be a breeze.

Comment: Well, that's true and my first solution was actually manually changing the path to project to ease my pain, as the variable with project path solved the `IDE & cmd` problem I had, but he insisted on me doing it automatically.

Comment: @AP11 Automatically = script, as Willis commented, so create a `.bat` file to do the compile and run. You should also consider using a build script.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into this. Thank you both guys Andreas and @WillisBlackburn I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you're using Maven to build your project, it can generate that launcher script for you automatically using the Application Assembler plug-in. That's what Java projects do; nobody expects users of a Java program to run it directly from the command line.