# Relative Paths in Java/Selenium/Maven

Tags: java, maven, csv, selenium

I have a test suite that links to a csv file stored on my local machine to check that certain values/string are as expected when I run tests. I am using Selenium(java) that I have linked with maven to run in a Jenkins build. I have written a method to read in the csv as a 2D array. This works fine with the file path `/home/usr/location`

However I need to place the csv file on many VMs to test production environments. When I try to change to a relative path such as `~/location` I get a file not found error.

I have all the correct permissions

Comment: Don't you want to put the file with Selenium project then if you need to share them across different machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to keep the CSV file with the build, and on the classpath (e.g. `src/test/resources/csv/`) or whatever. Then you should be able to look up the csv file from the classpath.

Or if you need a separate path, then e.g. `src/test/csv` should suffice. In this case you should be able to look up the path using something like `./src/test/csv` (as the working directory for a maven build is the project directory).

If you would really want to use the user's home directory, then you could go with the [System properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), looking up `user.home`, however then please be aware of the possible issues described more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java)

Alternatively, you could use some kind of environment (or application-managed) property, to make the CSV file located from somewhere on the file system, where you could configure it based on the actual environment. I mean something like starting the application or tests with `-Dcsv.location=/proper/location/data.csv`.