# File shortcut in Java

Tags: java, path, shortcut

I have a program which is build like this.

```
src 
 folder
  default package
   .java files

testfiles_folder
```

Is there a way to access the files in the `testfiles_folder` but without the absolute path because that is not the same on every computer that I will send this program?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
String file_directory = "testfiles_folder/testfileN.txt";
```

where N = 1, 2, ...

Comment: Relative paths? ../ to go one dir back... Or am I oversimplifying your question?

Comment: Use system property for test files folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use system paths.

Java 8 example:

> System.getProperty("user.home");

source: [System Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java)