# java.io.File cannot recognize "~" symbol of home dir?

Tags: java, file, io, directory

I tried this on mac:

```
touch ~/a.txt
```

And then java file:

```
import java.io.File;

public class testPwd {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        File f = new File("~/a.txt");
        System.out.println(f.exists());
    }
}
```

It prints out "false".

Why is this? Does java recognize the "~" symbol? If I use absolute path, this f.exists() returns true.

Any explanations?

Comment: `Does java recognize the "~" symbol?` — As you have demonstrated, it does not. What else are you asking?

Comment: That's a Unix convention; not sure if it's platform independent.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. Use `System.getProperty("user.home");` as demonstrated in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java to get the user's home directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this?

Because the `~` symbol is only understood by the Unix shell (and, confusingly, it was used in HTTP servers). Even if you wrote the program in C, it wouldn't understand `~` to designate the home directory of the current user.

To get the user's home directory, use `System.getProperty("user.home")`. (Answer from [What is the best way to find the users home directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java))