# Read multiple path within one single txt file using JAVA

Tags: java

I have several paths to read into the program from txt format file. In order to simply the process, I would like to stored all the paths/directory into one txt file and assign values to each path.

```
TXT file:
C:/folder1/data
D:/folder2/excel
E:/folder3/doc
```

JAVA:

```
final String Local_dir = System.getenv().get("USERNAME")
    String dir = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("C:/Users/$Local_dir/Desktop/sample_paths.txt"), "UTF-8")
    final String Path1 = dir.trim()
    final String Path2 = dir.trim()
    final String Path3 = dir.trim()
```

My question is how can I update the above code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file has carriage return and line feeds, and that your text file does not contain this first line `TXT file:`, I would suggest the following code:

```
final String Local_dir = System.getenv().get("USERNAME")
String dir = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("C:/Users/$Local_dir/Desktop/sample_paths.txt"), "UTF-8");

String[] lines = dir.split("\r\n");
final String Path1 = lines[0];
final String Path2 = lines[1];
final String Path3 = lines[2];
```

So it is a simple splitting to create the lines.

Edit: I also assume that your two first lines of code working for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the [home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java) from your computer and use the [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) method to get the whole content:

```java
String user = System.getProperty("user.home");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(user, "Desktop", "sample_paths.txt"));

String path1 = lines.get(0);
String path2 = lines.get(1);
String path3 = lines.get(2);
```