# Can't access working dir after application is installed?

Tags: java, windows

I'm working on developing a java application and I'm at the stage where I have an executable jar file that I want to convert into exe/dmg form so users can install it easily. Things are mostly going well, but when I run the program on windows after installation, the working directory is "C://Program Files (x86)/AppName" and I don't have write permission, which means all file operations fail. How do I fix this?

I assume I need to somehow find out which user is running the program and create a directory inside "C://users/user/AppData/Local" or something, but I don't know how to do that, or if that is even the preferred solution.

Comment: Looks like the answer has already been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java

Comment: @tgdavies Yeah, pretty much.