# cannot find files while app running on cloud foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, kerberos, cloud-foundry

When running the app locally, it works. However, after I build a jar with maven and push it to cloud foundry, it cannot find the krb5.keytab file through the local absolute file path
The krb5.keytab's path are setting in my application.yml file. e.g
keytab:
key: krb5.keytab
file: C:\Users\Documents\WorkSpace\MyProject\kafkatool\krb5.keytab

How do I need to change the file path of krb5.keytab so when it's running on cloud foundry the app can still find the keytab?

Answer (score 1):

When your Java application runs on CloudFoundry, it's running in a remote Linux container. It does not have access to your local file system and any files you reference need to be within the Linux container's filesystem, thus no `c:\` Windows-style paths are going to work.

Your application, when running on CF, lives in the `/home/vcap/app` directory (there's also a symlink at `/app` which points to `/home/vcap/app` that you can use if you want).

In addition, your application will be executed out of the `/home/vcap/app` directory so the current working directory will be `/home/vcap/app`.

Thus, if you need to reference files you can either reference them relative to the `/home/vcap/app` directory or you can prefix the `/home/vcap/app` to all paths and use a full path to the file.

---

If you don't like the idea of hard-coding `/home/vcap/app` into your application, you can fetch this directory dynamically by looking at the `HOME` environment variable. When your application runs, the `HOME` env variable points to `/home/vcap/app`.

Comment: for the HOME environment variable. can I refer the path as {user.home}\MyProject\kafkatool\krb5.keytab?

Comment: If you are in a shell, you'd need to use `$HOME`. Same if you are calling `System.getenv("HOME")` to fetch the env from Java. You can also use `System.getProperty("user.home")`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/586345/1585136