# app cannot find files through file path when running on cloud foundry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kerberos, spring-kafka, cloud-foundry

My project using application.yml to store properties.

```
spring:

  profiles: local
  
  kerberos:
  
    truststore:
  
      key: truststore.jks
  
      file: kafkatool-qa\\truststore.jks
  
    keytab:
  
      key: krb5.keytab
  
      file: kafkatool-qa\\krb5.keytab
```

The truststore and krb5.keytab are located at "C:\Users\Documents\producers\kafkatool-qa\krb5.keytab". producers\ is my project directory.

When I run the app locally, it can located the 2 files and works. But when I run this app on cloud foundry. It cannot located the file.

Is there anyway to let the app address the krb5.keytab and truststore.jks when it runs on cloud foundry?

Comment: Can I just set their paths as '{user.home}\kafkatool-qa\krb5.keytab'?

Comment: Sure, you could, but what is `user.home` in cloud foundry? You have to upload the files there, and it's not really clear how you're doing that (your C drive doesn't exist there). What is `kafkatool-qa`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer kafkatool-qa is just a folder where I keep the files the code will reference

Comment: Okay, and how does that get into cloud foundry? And last I checked, that uses Linux containers so those slashes need reversed, and should only be one. Forward slashes are only for Windows paths. Much of this was already [answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029231/2308683), but you have not told us how files get **uploaded** to the remote server.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I uploaded file by package a jar with maven->login to cloud foundry in intellij terminal->cf push the jar file with java buildpack. Thanks I will try to reverse the slashes in the path.

Comment: Have you tried building the container _locally_ (e.g. `mvn spring-boot:build-image`) and running that with `docker run`?